# “at” command does not execute shell script

Tags: linux, macos, at

I want to run a script at a specific time. I found that at command is the solution but the shell script i attached with it is not being executed. I used below multiple commands but no use.

`` echo "`./time.sh`" | at -t 07101805 ``

`` echo `./time.sh` | at -t 07101805 ``

`at -t 07101738 <./time.sh`

`at -t 07101737 -f ./time.sh`

I also launched the `atrun` using the following command

`sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist`

The job is listed like below:

`at -l`

31  Fri Jul 10 18:15:00 2020

And as time passes it goes away from the list also which means that the at command is working but it does not executes the script.

The shell script is simple one as below:

`#!/bin/sh`

`` echo "the time is `date`" >time.txt ``

`echo "yes the at command worked">>time.txt`

Please share if there is another way to do it. Thanks

Comment: Are you intentionally using backtick expansion?

Comment: What are you trying to do, run `time.sh` at some point in the future?  Run the output of `time.sh` at some point in the future?

Comment: First of all, provide the full path to your script. at doesn't have your context of current working directory.

Comment: On the contrary: It knows all about the current environment, and stores it all in the job file. All the exports, your actual PATH, and it cd's into the directory you ran at from.

Comment: @jsbillings Which backticks you are talking of... the ones in the shell only outputs date and time so that i can check if my command is working correctly...

Comment: I want ti run time.sh in some time in future... execute the shell in some time in future...@AndyDalton

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Thank you for your comment... it is just for the simplicity i did not mention the path for the sake of question... itherwise i am using a complete path... no use...

Comment: @UbaidIlyas yes, back ticks are absolutely the wrong syntax. But `at -f ./time.sh timespec` should be fine, assuming timespec is correct.

Comment: @jsbillings  I would like to see outputs from `atq` and `at -c _job_` from repeats of those two. They both work for me, even with time.sh not being executable, even with retrospective time (they run immediately).

Comment: @jsbillings yes i tried `at -f ./time.sh timespec`. The job is scheduled properly and after the specified time it goes away from `at -l` but the script does not executes.

Answer (score 3):

at takes two kinds of time: fixed and intuitive.

at -t 202111231735 is year 2021 month 11 day 23rd time 17:35

at now + 3 days; at 0700; at 1200 next tuesday do what you might expect.

```
paul $ echo foo | at now + 3 days
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 16 at Tue Jul 14 16:55:00 2020
paul $ date
Sat 11 Jul 16:56:02 BST 2020
paul $ echo foo | at 0700
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 17 at Sun Jul 12 07:00:00 2020
paul $ echo foo | at 1200 next tuesday
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 18 at Tue Jul 14 12:00:00 2020
paul $ atq
18  Tue Jul 14 12:00:00 2020 a paul
17  Sun Jul 12 07:00:00 2020 a paul
16  Tue Jul 14 16:55:00 2020 a paul
paul $
```

Your back-ticked commands are completely wrong: they will execute your script right now, and stuff their actual stdout into the upcoming job. As you redirect all the output at the moment the job is created, the job it sets up is actually empty -- there is no stdout to put in there.

Reading a bunch of commands into at is also flawed. They will be run by /bin/sh, not by the shell in any shebang you might have. If you really must have several lines of commands, use a HereDoc and be very careful about whether shell expansions happen when you create the job, or when it finally runs.

Just echo the name of the script (and any args) into at. Then, at's shell will see the shebang and run the right shell. Also, any fixes you make to the script will be effective because at has not yet read the actual script. You don't even need a pathname, because at will reinstate your cwd and your environment before it executes your script.

The intuitive timespec for date is documented (on my Mint) at `/usr/share/doc/at/timespec`. It is in the form of a Bachus-Naur grammar, so not terribly convenient. Using `at 07101805` resolves to the undefined token `concatenated_date`, which seems to assume `MMDDCCYY` for CC >= 1900, current century for CC == 00, and relative to 1900 for CC in {01..18}.

See your stored jobs like:

```
paul $ at -c 18
#!/bin/sh
# atrun uid=1000 gid=1000
# mail paul 0
umask 22
XDG_VTNR=8; export XDG_VTNR
... 50 lies of setup.
COLORTERM=mate-terminal; export COLORTERM
XAUTHORITY=/home/paul/.Xauthority; export XAUTHORITY
cd /home/paul || {
     echo 'Execution directory inaccessible' >&2
     exit 1
}
foo
```

Comment: The time specification is [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS] so 07101805 is correct, optional are by default CC=20 YY=20.
`echo path/to/time.sh | at -t 07141535`
job 39 at Tue Jul 14 15:35:00 2020
`echo time.sh | at -t 07141537`
job 41 at Tue Jul 14 15:37:00 2020
`at -t 07141539 -f time.sh`
job 42 at Tue Jul 14 15:39:00 2020
`at -t 07141541 -f path/to/time.sh`
job 43 at Tue Jul 14 15:41:00 2020
`at -l`
42 Tue Jul 14 15:39:00 2020
43 Tue Jul 14 15:41:00 2020
39 Tue Jul 14 15:35:00 2020
41 Tue Jul 14 15:37:00 2020


at -l (after 15:41 gives nothing telling that the jobs are executed)

Comment: Can you check your Linux mail system? `at` will email you any output from the job (errors or non-redirected output) into your user mailbox. Would also like to see `at -c <job> | head` and `at -c <job> | tail` from a fresh job submission before it gets run. at will not tell you about jobs it has already run.

Comment: @UbaidIlyas Sorry - I tried your initial posts without the -t option. I corrected my answer in this respect yesterday, and added a note about the undefined nature of my usage. It is usually wise to check the time when you set up the job.